# Disable VFP Command Button on Click

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I currently have an issue where users are button mashing a custom VFP Lead convert page and converting a lead into multiple Accounts. Based on the direction of this [POST](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201587/how-to-disable-a-apex-command-button) I was able to partially resolve this issue by disabling the convert button. The problem is I have two sets of buttons, one on top and on the bottom and this fix is only applying to the top set of buttons. See picture below:

[image: example]

I would like to disable both the top and bottom 'Convert' button when they are clicked. Can anyone assist with this? Below is my current VFP Code:

```
<apex:page id="LeadConvertOpptyOption" standardController="Lead" extensions="customLeadConvert">
    <head>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS2018, 'styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css')}" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <style>
            .opptyRecType{
                color: #4a4a56;
                font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 91%;
                float: left;    
            }
        
            #checkbox {
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                console.log( "ready!" );
                var x = $('[id$=checkbox]').is(':checked');
                if(!x){
                    $(".opptyRecType").hide();
                }
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function markClicked(){
                var x = $('[id$=checkbox]').is(':checked');
                console.log('ready x:: ' + x);
                if(x) {
                    // Checkbox is checked..
                    $(".opptyRecType").show();
                } else {
                    // Checkbox is not checked..
                    $(".opptyRecType").hide();
                }
            }
            
                                function disableBttn() {
                    console.log('Button Clicked');
                    var btn = document.querySelector("[id$='ConvertBttn']");
                    btn.className = 'btn btnDisabled';
                    btn.disabled = 'disabled';
                    return false;
                }
        </script>
    </head>

<!--"{!$Component.LeadConvertOpptyOption.ConvertForm.ConvertLeadBlock.ConvertButtons.ConvertBttn}"-->

    <apex:pageMessages />
    
    <apex:form id="ConvertForm">
        <script>

        </script>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Convert Lead" id="ConvertLeadBlock" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons id="ConvertButtons">
                <apex:commandButton value="Convert" id="ConvertBttn" onclick="return disableBttn()" action="{!convertLeadToAcctContOppty}"/><!--convert button--> <!-- this will either convert the lead to just an account and contact OR all three oppty, acct, and cont-->
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/> <!--cancel button-->
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Create Opportunity?"/>
                        <!--<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!objLead.CreateConvertedOppty__c}" onClick="markClicked()" id="checkbox"/>-->
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!createOppty}" selected="true" onClick="markClicked()" id="checkbox"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <!--only display this section if the value of inputCheckbox == true-->
                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="opptyRecType">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel id="lblOppRecType" value="Opportunity Record Type "/>
                        <apex:selectList id="ddlOppRecType" size="1" multiselect="False" value="{!objRecType}">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!OpportunityRecordType}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here are the following snippets that I updated in the process of resolving this issue:

To Disable the button on click:

```
                                function disableBttn() {
                    console.log('Button Clicked');
                    var btn = document.querySelector("[id$='ConvertBttn']");
                    btn.className = 'btn btnDisabled';
                    btn.disabled = 'disabled';
                    return false;
                }
```

To call the JS to Disable the button:

```
                <apex:commandButton value="Convert" id="ConvertBttn" onclick="return disableBttn()" action="{!convertLeadToAcctContOppty}"/>
```

How can I get the bottom 'Convert' button to be disabled as well? Any Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't **need** the bottom buttons you could add `location="top"` to your `pageBlockButtons` tag. If you do need both sets of buttons, you'll need to determine the id of the second button element in the page and update this markup `var btn = document.querySelector("[id$='ConvertBttn']");` to select it in addition to the first button.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the suggestion/answer

Comment: @MarkPond I am finding that when I include the ```onclick="return disableBttn()"``` the action is not being called within the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery:

```
function disableBttn() {
    $("[id$='ConvertBttn']").addClass("btn btnDisabled");
    $("[id$='ConvertBttn']").attr("disabled","disabled");
    return false;
}
```

querySelector only brings back the first matched item. You would want to querySelectorAll, or use the jQuery above, which does the same thing.

Comment: I am finding that when i include the ```onclick="return disableBttn()"``` the action is not being called within the button.

Comment: The button cannot be disabled before the form is submitted. Disabled form elements aren't included in the POST - the result is that the server does not know which button was clicked and so the related action is not called. Here's a related question I helped with a few years ago that may help you too. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/7729/660

Comment: @Max Return false prevents the default behavior (in this case, form submission). Just don't return a value, it should work as you expect